# The cost of Realtime Database after 360MB/day?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone have any clue how much does Firebase Realtime Database cost after the 360MB/day limit is exceeded on that day? Just on that particular day, the next day will be less than 360MB again.

If you have any clue, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page:

> GB Downloaded: $1/GB

So for all data over 360MB in a day you pay $1 per gigabyte.